# Reverse guessing game (java)

Tags: java, random

I am supposed to be doing a reverse guessing game where the user picks a number and the computer guesses but I am having a hard time getting the computer to not repeat what it has already guessed. But this is what I have done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    intro();
    game (console);

}

/*
 * This method just prints out the intro before the game.
 */

public static void intro ()
{
    System.out.println("This program has you, the user, choose a number");
    System.out.println("between 1 and 10, then I, the computer, will try");
    System.out.println("my best to guess it.");
    System.out.println();
}
 /*
  * This method is the game part that is going to ask the user to choose a number (1-10)
  */
public static boolean  game (Scanner console)
{
    String user;
    int min= 1;
    int max = 10;
    int computer;
    int numberOfGuesses = 0;
    boolean again = false; 
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("User, what is your number? ");
    int usernumber = console.nextInt();

    while (!again)
    {
        if (min==max)
        {
            computer= min;
        }
        else
        {
            computer = Math.abs (rand.nextInt()) % (max - min) + min;
        }

        System.out.print("Is it " + computer + "? (y/n) ");
         user = console.next();


        if (user.charAt(0) == 'y')
        {
            numberOfGuesses++;
            System.out.println("I go your number of " + usernumber + " correct in " + numberOfGuesses + " guess(es).");
            again = true;
            return again;
        }

        if (user.charAt(0) == 'n')
        {


            if(min >=computer)
            {
                min = computer +1; 
            }
            else
            {
                max = computer -1 ;
            }
            numberOfGuesses++;
            again = false;
        }

    }


    return again;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Consider trying to using a boolean array and every time a number is guessed change the value at the array[value-1] to true. Then when the computer guesses before printing to the screen check if that value is in the array. If it isn't awesome use that, I'd not guess again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Set' to store the already generated numbers and check whether the number already exists, by simply adding it to `Set`, e.g.:

```
Set<Double> generated = new HashSet<>();

while(!again)
{

if (min==max)
{
    computer= min;
}
else
{
    computer = Math.abs (rand.nextInt()) % (max - min) + min;
}

if(!generated.add(computer)){
    continue;
}
```

`add` method of `Set` returns `false` if the element already exists. By this way, you can check whether the number is already generated.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) is the Javadoc of `add` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest of codes:

```
boolean hasValue[] = new boolean[10];
    while(true) {
        System.out.print("User, what is your number: ");
        int usernumber = sc.nextInt();
        int guess = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;
        hasValue[guess] = true;
        if(usernumber != guess && !hasValue[usernumber])
            System.out.println("Oops!");
        else {              
            System.out.println("Bingo!");
            break;
        }
    }
```